# How can I put JSON object in setQueryParameter parameters?

Tags: javascript, json, ibm-mobilefirst

In Mobilefirst Platform 8.0, in order to send a request to an adapter procedure I can use something like this

```
resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("params", "['Washington', 'United States']");
```

But this is for 2 string values. How can I send a JSON object instead of a string?

I would like to send something like this:

```
var request = {name: 'George', suername: 'Williams', Id: '1234'};
 resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("params", request);
```

If yes, what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following approaches:

1. Pass it directly, but as a string...

   ```
   resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("params", “[{’name’ : ‘bob’, ‘’age’ : 25}, 'United States']");
   ```
2. Create a JSONArray and pass it

   ```
   JSONArray params = new JSONArray();
   params.putObject(myJsonObject);
   resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("params", params);
   ```